# Responsive design: Float text over image

Tags: html, css, hover, responsive, floating

I have yet to find the answer to this. I have a div with image that grows with :hover. I want to overlay some text that is static during hover and does not interfere with the anchor tag. I also need this design to be responsive so that then the text is always in the middle of the image. I have tried Display:Table and Table-cell...There is some portion of my CSS that doesn't agree with everything I try.

I have been able to get as far as placing the text inside of an Absolute div but I don't want to specify the exact pixel location of the text as this is not responsive.

```
<style>
#AOB{
height: 700px;
position: relative;
padding: 30px 200px 0px;
}


.innerBlock {
float: left;
display:block;
position: relative;
}

#AOB .innerBlock {
width: 33.2%;
height: 50%;
overflow:hidden;
}

#AOB img{
height:100%;
width:  100%;

}

#AOB img:hover{
-webkit-transform:scale(1.05);
-ms-transform:scale(1.05);
transform:scale(1.05);
transition: all 0.2s ease;
}


.innerBlockText{
position:absolute;
top: 100px;
left: 100px;
z-index:1;
}



</style>

<div id="AOB">
  <div id="one" class="innerBlock">
    <a href = "http://www.google.com">
     <div class="innerBlockText">
     beach
     </div>
     <img  src="https://www.weebly.com/editor/uploads/2/1/6/7/21673280/custom_themes/537557073923231080/files/images/beach.png">
    </a> 
  </div>

  <div id="two" class="innerBlock">
    <a href = "http://www.google.com">
     <img src="https://www.weebly.com/editor/uploads/2/1/6/7/21673280/custom_themes/537557073923231080/files/images/beach.png">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div id="three" class="innerBlock">
    <a href = "http://www.google.com">
     <img src="https://www.weebly.com/editor/uploads/2/1/6/7/21673280/custom_themes/537557073923231080/files/images/beach.png">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div id="four" class="innerBlock">
    <a href = "http://www.google.com">
    <img src="https://www.weebly.com/editor/uploads/2/1/6/7/21673280/custom_themes/537557073923231080/files/images/beach.png">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div id="five" class="innerBlock">
    <a href = "http://www.google.com">
     <img src="https://www.weebly.com/editor/uploads/2/1/6/7/21673280/custom_themes/537557073923231080/files/images/beach.png">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div id="six" class="innerBlock">
    <a href = "http://www.google.com">
     <img src="https://www.weebly.com/editor/uploads/2/1/6/7/21673280/custom_themes/537557073923231080/files/images/beach.png">
    </a>
  </div>



</div>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
.innerBlockText {
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    left: 50%;
}
```

(Putting it inside your current selector, of course).  The top/left 50% mmove it to those positions in relation to the parent; the translate moves it in relation to itself, centering it.

https://jsfiddle.net/9Lvmjt5g/4/